# UnitTest ModelForm having ModelChoiceField with Mock Data

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, modelform

I've been trying to write unit test for my ModelForm, that has a ModelChoiceField. I'm creating the Form instance with mock data.

Here's my model:

```
# models.py
class Menu(models.Model):
    dish = models.ForeignKey(Dish, default=None)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)

# forms.py
class MenuForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Menu
        fields = ('dish', 'price',)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(MenuForm, self).clean()
        price = cleaned_data.get('price', None)
        dish = cleaned_data.get('dish', None)

        # Some validation below
        if price < 70:
            self.add_error('price', 'Min price threshold')
            return cleaned_data
```

Here's my test case:

```
class MenuFormTest(TestCase):
    def test_price_threshold(self):
        mock_dish = mock.Mock(spec=Dish)
        form_data = {
            'dish': mock_dish,
            'price': 80,
        }
        form = forms.MenuForm(data=form_data)
        self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
```

This fails with the following error:

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>dish<ul class="errorlist"><li>Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

How to make that avoid throw that error. `form.is_valid()` should have been `True` there. Is there a way I can patch the `ModelChoiceField's` `queryset`? I tried to patch form's `dish` field `clean()` method like below:

```
form = forms.MenuForm(data=form_data)
dish_clean_patcher = mock.patch.object(form.fields['dish'], 'clean')
dish_clean_patch = dish_clean_patcher.start()
dish_clean_patch.return_value = mock_dish

self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
```

Then it looks like, it fails while saving form data to model instance in `_post_clean()` method. Here's the Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1305, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "/vagrant/myapp/tests/test_forms.py", line 51, in test_price_threshold
    self.assertFalse(form.is_valid())
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 185, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 177, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 396, in full_clean
    self._post_clean()
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 427, in _post_clean
    self.instance = construct_instance(self, self.instance, opts.fields, construct_instance_exclude)
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 62, in construct_instance
    f.save_form_data(instance, cleaned_data[f.name])
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 874, in save_form_data
    setattr(instance, self.name, data)
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 632, in __set__
    instance._state.db = router.db_for_write(instance.__class__, instance=value)
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 300, in _route_db
    if instance is not None and instance._state.db:
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 716, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("Mock object has no attribute %r" % name)
AttributeError: Mock object has no attribute '_state'
```

How do I avoid that part? I don't want it to look into `instance._state.db` at all.

Am I testing the form correctly? Or should I instead of calling `form.is_valid()`, just call `form.clean()` method, by patching the `super(MenuForm, self).clean()` method completely, and check `form.errors`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say calling `form.is_valid()` is a good way to test a form. I am not sure about mocking the model though.

[Internally the form is calling `get_limit_choices_to` on your `dish` field](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L307) (Which Django is currently creating for you).

[You would need to mock the `dish` field's `.queryset` or `get_limit_choices_to` here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L310), (or somewhere else in the call stack that makes the values here meaningless) in some way to achieve what you want.

Alternatively it would be much simpler to create a `Dish` inside your test and let Django's internals keep doing what they are doing.

```
class MenuFormTest(TestCase):
    def test_price_threshold(self):
        dish = Dish.objects.create(
            # my values here
        )
        form_data = {
            'dish': dish.id,
            'price': 80,
        }
        form = MenuForm(data=form_data)
        self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
```

If you are really set on not using Django's test database, one strategy could be to mock the `MenuForm.clean` and `MenuForm._post_clean`:

```
class MenuFormTest(TestCase):
    def test_price_threshold(self):
        mock_dish = mock.Mock(spec=Dish)
        form_data = {
            'dish': 1,
            'price': 80,
        }
        form = MenuForm(data=form_data)
        form.fields['dish'].clean = lambda _: mock_dish
        form._post_clean = lambda : None
        self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
```

You will need to ask yourself what your goal is with this test if you are going to do this.

Comment: Using `Model.objects.create` seems like a better choice than using `mock.Mock`. I mean why use a library when things can be done just as easily without it.

Answer (score 0):

If think your test is not "unit" enought. You seem to want to test the price treshold right ? Maybe you could do something like that :

```
# forms.py
class MenuForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Menu
        fields = ('dish', 'price',)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(MenuForm, self).clean()
        price = cleaned_data.get('price', None)
        dish = cleaned_data.get('dish', None)

        # Some validation below
        if not self._is_price_valid(price):
            self.add_error('price', 'Min price threshold')
            return cleaned_data

    def _is_price_valid(self, price):
        return price >= 70
```

And your test :

```
class MenuFormTest(TestCase):
    def test_price_threshold(self):
        form = forms.MenuForm()
        self.assertTrue(form._is_price_valid(80))
```

I agree that for this example it's a little "overkill" to just add a method ta returns a simple comparison but if you just want to test the price threshold without bothering with form validation process internal to Django it's not bad to isolate it